# Hostname myweb.intweb.net provided via SNI and hostname mysecondweb.intweb.net provided via HTTP are different

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have been having an SSL website in one of my servers for a while without have any issues, then I had to add a second SSL website in the same server using the same port (4433). My configuration looks like this: I have two nginx front end and apache back end websites in my server, both with the same exact configuration (except for the server name, etc).

My problems started to arise that when I hit one of the websites and then I visit the second website, then I see the following error in the browser:

> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Then I looked at apache error log and I see the following error in there:

> [Fri Nov 09 16:17:51.247904 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 18614] AH02032:
>   Hostname firstwebsite.intweb.net provided via SNI and hostname
>   secondwebsite.intweb.net provided via HTTP are different

So, I decided to isolate the problem to see if the problem was coming from nginx or the way apache process the data received from nginx. First, I try to do it with nginx by just having nginx to be in the front and backend with the proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:44133 call.

What it was a susprise for me is that the problem is in nginx, as you can see in the following curl calls, I could see that in fact the backend sni and the backend hostheader were for some reason different in the second website I try to hit.

Here is the proof:

```
[root@webdev http]# curl -I https://firstwebsite.intweb.net
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Thu, 29 Nov 2018 00:08:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-backend-ssl-sni: firstwebsite.intweb.net
X-backend-hostheader: firstwebsite.intweb.net
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

[root@webdev http]# curl -I https://secondwebsite.intweb.net
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Thu, 29 Nov 2018 00:08:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-backend-ssl-sni: firstwebsite.intweb.net
X-backend-hostheader: secondwebsite.intweb.net
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

And this will happen the other way around as well, I mean, if I call the seconwebsite first and then the firstwebsite second, I will get the backend-sni and the backend hostheader with the same value for the secondwebsite but different for the firstwebsite. It would be like if there was like any kind of caching or something similar. I really don't have any idea what could be happening.

Here are the configuration files for each one of the websites:

First website conf: https://paste.ngx.cc/9b

Second website conf: https://paste.ngx.cc/43

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by adding this line of code in my nginx.conf file:

```
proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
```

apparently there's a bug in OpenSSL. I tested it running the following code:

```
openssl genrsa -out fookey.pem 2048
openssl req -x509 -key fookey.pem -out foocert.pem -days 3650 -subj '/CN=testkey.invalid.example'

openssl s_server -accept localhost:30889 -cert foocert.pem -key fookey.pem -state -servername key1.example -cert2 foocert.pem -key2 fookey.pem

openssl s_client -connect localhost:30889 -sess_out /tmp/tempsslsess -servername key1.example

openssl s_client -connect localhost:30889 -sess_in /tmp/tempsslsess -servername key2.example
```

observe key1.example in the SNI info reported by s_server for both requests.  ("Hostname in TLS extension: "...)

If s_server is restarted, and the s_client connections/sessions are re-run using key2.example first and key1.example second, observe key2.example in the SNI info reported by s_server for both requests.

Furthermore, I just tested on a different machine, and sometimes SNI appears to be absent in the second requests.

shouldn't s_client filter session use so that if it knows SNI info before selecting a cached session, it only selects one that matches the intended SNI name?  And if it doesn't have a SNI name when it's searching for a session to re-use, shouldn't it still double check when it's provided (later, before connecting) SNI info, to make sure it's identical to SNI in the saved session it picked, and not use the saved session if they differ?

It seems to me if the SNI specified by the client app ever differs from the SNI seen by the server, that's not good.

this was discovered by someone reporting a problem using nginx to reverse proxy to apache, with apache warning that the SNI hostname didn't match the Host: header, despite the nginx config explicitly setting Host: and apache-side SNI to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Apache 2.2 (that you use; end of life btw) strictly forbids different SNI hostname and Host hostname. Apache 2.4 relaxes that condition and only failing if:

"The request does not select the virtual host that was
selected by the SNI and its SSL parameters are different"

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x/modules/ssl/ssl_engine_kernel.c?view=annotate#l335

nginx reuses backend connections if keepalive is enabled but you don't have that in your configs.

Looking into nginx source code there are other possible conditions:

```
         * set u->keepalive if response has no body; this allows to keep
         * connections alive in case of r->header_only or X-Accel-Redirect
```

Solutions:
switch to apache 2.4.

Workarounds:
do not use https between frontend and backend (especially that in your setup both are on the same machine). mod_rpaf and mod_remoteip will help exposing "fake" ssl information to other apache modules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think the configuration files are available anymore but you can see my real problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529625/hostname-myfirstweb-intweb-net-provided-via-sni-and-hostname-mysecondweb-intweb

Comment: Regarding your suggestion about not using https between the front and the back end, I just have a question about that. Should I just pass the request from nginx to apache as http, so then only nginx will be the only one receiving the connection as https?

Comment: @VaTo: yes, exactly. But now apps (php for example) will see that connection is unencrypted. You can use `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme' on nginx side which mod_rpaf (external apache module) will use to set proper internal apache variables indicating http/https that nginx got in request.